# iOS >7 - Table text is getting cut off

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Here is my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UIFont *cellFont;

        if(delegate.iPad){
            cellFont= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:28.0];
        }else{
            cellFont= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
        }
        CGSize size = [cellText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: myFont}];

        // Values are fractional -- you should take the ceilf to get equivalent values
        CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(ceilf(size.width), ceilf(size.height));
        tableHeight2 = tableHeight2 + labelSize.height;


        NSStringDrawingContext *ctx = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
        NSAttributedString *aString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:cellText];
        UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        [calculationView setAttributedText:aString];
        CGRect textRect = [calculationView.text boundingRectWithSize:table2.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cellFont} context:ctx];
        return = textRect.size.height;
}
```

The last line or so of text is getting cut off for some reason, even though it seems to be calculating the height properly. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons this can happen :

1) **AutoLayout** or **AutoResize** issue ie not set properly.

2) **Height** returned in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is wrong.

**Explaination** : Here you should return height with (text height + top padding + bottom padding)

```
 return = textRect.size.height+(2*label.frame.origin.x);
```

Comment: I had to turn autolayout off because I'm using ECSlidingViewController, which means when the slide menu slides out it would resize the tables and make them look funny. I'll try the other option.

Comment: Oh, wait, I'm not using a label, I'm using cell.textlabel. I'm not sure how to include your fix.

Comment: Get cell from indexpath and then use cell's textlabel